# Workflow 2013 get data from user profile - System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I am trying to get data from

http://sp13/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties

in my WF2013....But there is an authorization problem

{"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang ......

If I test this link in web browser everything is OK and I can access data.... So I try to add almost all permissions to my WF service but still without any success....I am testing this in SharePoint 2013. 
[image]

Please can some help me with this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check the add-in permissions AND the current user permissions. Both of them should be granted the permissions to perform the operation.